How to add @SecurityRequirement(name = "X-API-KEY") from microservice swagger in Central Swagger in spring cloud Gateway
I have an issue when I add authorizations from spring gateway like this:


When I hit the swagger API, the API key is not sent to the API, and get error like this:

The log in microservice does not detect the API key that I send from gateway:

The code that I have in spring gate way is like this:
import org.springdoc.core.properties.SwaggerUiConfigParameters;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.cloud.gateway.route.RouteDefinition;
import org.springframework.cloud.gateway.route.RouteDefinitionLocator;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import java.util.Objects;

@Configuration
public class SwaggerConfig {

    @Bean
    public CommandLineRunner openApiGroups(
            RouteDefinitionLocator locator,
            SwaggerUiConfigParameters swaggerUiConfigParameters) {
        return args -> Objects.requireNonNull(locator
                .getRouteDefinitions().collectList().block())
                .stream()
                .map(RouteDefinition::getId)
                .filter(id -> id.matches(".*-service"))
                .map(id -> id.replace("-service", ""))
                .forEach(swaggerUiConfigParameters::addGroup);
    }
}

and the microservice is like this:
import io.swagger.v3.oas.models.Components;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.models.OpenAPI;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.models.info.Info;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.models.info.License;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.models.security.SecurityRequirement;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.models.security.SecurityScheme;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class SwaggerConfig {
    @Bean
    public OpenAPI customOpenAPI(){
        final String API_KEY_HEADER_NAME = "X-API-KEY";
        final String securitySchemeName = "ApiKeyAuth";
        return new OpenAPI()
                .info(new Info().title("API Documentation")
                        .version("v1")
                        .description("This is the API documentation for our application.")
                        .license(new License().name("Apache 2.0").url("http://springdoc.org")))
                .addSecurityItem(new SecurityRequirement().addList(API_KEY_HEADER_NAME))
                .components(new Components()
                        .addSecuritySchemes(API_KEY_HEADER_NAME, new SecurityScheme()
                                .name(API_KEY_HEADER_NAME)
                                .type(SecurityScheme.Type.APIKEY)
                                .in(SecurityScheme.In.HEADER)
                                .name(API_KEY_HEADER_NAME)));
    }
}

and the application.yaml in spring gateway is like this:
server:
  port: 5656

spring:
  application:
    name: api-gateway
  cloud:
    gateway:
      httpclient:
        connect-timeout: 10000
        response-timeout: 7s
      routes:
        - id: ms-idm-service
          uri: "http://localhost:6992/"
          predicates:
            - Path=/api/v1/menu/* , /v3/api-docs/ms-idm
        - id: ms-master-data-service
          uri: "http://localhost:6991/"
          predicates:
            - Path=/api/v1/role-code/* , /v3/api-docs/ms-master-data
          filters:
            - AddRequestHeader=X-API-KEY , f098c80f-f140-4f92-9db6-98b47b84c2b7

    discovery:
      enabled: true

resilience4j:
  time limiter:
    configs:
      default:
        timeoutDuration: 7000
        cancelRunningFuture: true

logging:
  level:
    org:
      springframework:
        cloud.gateway: DEBUG
        http.server.reactive: DEBUG
        web.reactive: DEBUG

This is the example of microservice controller:
@GetMapping
    @Operation(summary = "Get All Role Code",security = {@SecurityRequirement(name = "X-API-KEY")})
    public ResponseEntity<ApiResponse> getAll(){
        List<TRoleCodeResponseDTO> tRoleCodeResponseDTOS = tRoleCodeService.getAll();
        return responseBuilderHelper.buildSingleResponse(ResponseEnum.SUCCESS, API_VERSION_1,
                Integer.toString(Constants.OK), Constants.GLB_MESSAGE_SUCCESS, tRoleCodeResponseDTOS);
    }

I have tried like this but nothing happened:
import org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.GatewayFilter;
import org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.GatewayFilterChain;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.server.ServerWebExchange;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

@Component
public class ApiKeyAuthorizationFilter implements GatewayFilter {

    private static final String API_KEY_PARAM = "f098c80f-f140-4f92-9db6-98b47b84c2b7";
    private static final String AUTHORIZATION_HEADER = "Authorization";

    @Override
    public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, GatewayFilterChain chain) {
        String apiKey = exchange.getRequest().getQueryParams().getFirst(API_KEY_PARAM);

        if (apiKey != null && !apiKey.isEmpty()) {
            HttpHeaders headers = exchange.getRequest().getHeaders();
            headers.set(AUTHORIZATION_HEADER, "Bearer " + apiKey);

            return chain.filter(exchange);
        }

        return Mono.error(new NullPointerException());
    }
}

